# getting error The type org.apache.http.HttpResponse is not accessible when using apache http core and http client libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, http

I am trying to import the httpclient, string entity class and all the other classes that are mentioned but none of the classes are getting imported. I have added the jar files to the build path, but nothing seems to resolve the errors. can someone please help me resolve it. im stuck on it for almost a day now.

```
package httpRequests;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class http {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String IP = "api.cle.org.pk";
        String postURL = "https://" + IP+ "/v1/synth";
        HttpClient   httpClient    = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost     post          = new HttpPost(postURL);
        StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity(JSON_MSG,"UTF-8");
        post.setEntity(postingString);
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
        String JSON_Response=convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
                    
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What Eclipse version are you using and what Java version are you using?

Comment: @Abra java 13.0.2 2020-01-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8) eclipse version Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)

Comment: Did you look at the **Problems** view? From the Eclipse menu: **Window > Show View > Problems**